How to handle a DTO in both polymorphic and non-polymorphic endpoints with Jackson?
I work with SpringBoot 3.2 and kotlin. I have a usecase for a polymorphic api which I do with some jackson annotations. This already works:
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(Feature1::class, name = "feature1"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(Feature2::class, name = "feature2"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(Feature3::class, name = "feature3")
)
interface FeatureDto {
    val id: UUID?
    fun toDoc(): Feature
}

However, I have another endpoint where I want to use fields with the specific type of a feature e.g.:
data class AnotherDto(
    val id: UUID? = null,
    val name: String,

    var feature1: Feature1Dto? = null
)

Now, deserialization does not work without the type string since my Feature1 is a FeatureDto. Can I get around using the type string when its not necessary?
